# Increment and decrement button function in next.js typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am new to typescript and want to create increment and decrement button function in next.js project being written in typescript.

```
export default function Home() { 
  return ( 
    <div className={styles.container}> 
       <form className={`wrapper ${styles.wrapper}`}>
          <div className={styles.headWrapper}>
            <h2>Скорость</h2>
            <input type="number" id="input" min='1'/>
            <h3>сек.</h3>
          </div>
          <div className={styles.controlBtns}>
            <button id="minus">-</button>
            <button id="plus">+</button>
          </div>
       </form>
    </div> 
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React hooks approach for your use case can look like this:

```
const App: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState<number>(0);
  
  const inc = (event) => {
    setCount(count + 1);
  };
  
  const dec = () => {
    setCount(count - 1);
  }
 
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={dec}>-</button>

      <input type="number" value={count} />

      <button onClick={inc}>+</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

You can use it in your Next.js project. Check the full example: https://codepen.io/bgoodman/pen/xxxqggK